# SQLite alternative to DataTable.Load()

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable

When I try to load a DataTable from a DataReader it throws a "NotSupportedException".

Simple question, what alternative should I use to replace this code :

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
SqliteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();    
dataTable.Load(reader);
```

Comment: Try DataAdapter instead of Datareader. Use Fill method

Comment: Already tried, it didn't work either because there is no such thing as SqliteDataAdapter in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite library. Another idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an alternative! Version 2.1.0 was just released, which fixes this issue.

Comment: Sounds great but Version 2.1.0 of what? Microsoft.Data.Sqlite and Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core ?